# Add Transition File in Navigation Graph of Android Application

Tags: android, animation, kotlin, navigation, transition

I want to add an explode transition in my next fragment using the latest Navigation pattern "Navigation Graph".How to add a transition XML file(@transition/fade or @transition/slide or @transiton/explode) into Navigation Graph of android app.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to define the desired transition in your navigation graph like this:

```
<fragment        

    // here your fragment is defined    

    <action
          android:id="@+id/your_action_id"
          app:destination="@id/yourDestinationFragment"
          app:enterAnim="@anim/fade_in"
          app:exitAnim="@anim/fade_out"
          app:popEnterAnim="@anim/fade_in"
          app:popExitAnim="@anim/fade_out" />
</fragment>
```

Note that you can define different animations for entering and leaving a fragment.
The animations you define will go into the /res/anim folder. You might have to create it if you don't find it.